# Displaying a form on button click in MFC application

Tags: visual-studio-2010, forms, visual-c++, mfc

I have an MFC application. In this MFC there is a dialog box having some button controls. There is a button control named "play" to display Live Camera Image on another button control.  I have added one form by right click on the project and added a "pictureBox" in to this form.

What I want is when I click on the "play" button control then this form will be opened and the live camera will be shown on the "pictureBox" instead of another button control.

As I am new to MFC application I don't know how I will open from on click of the "play" button control.
I have used this code for opening form

```
PvSimpleUISample::display^ obj;
    obj=gcnew PvSimpleUISample::display();
```

But this is showing error like
PvSimpleUISampleDlg.cpp(740): error C2653: 'PvSimpleUISample' : is not a class or namespace name

```
PvSimpleUISampleDlg.cpp(740): error C2065: 'display' : undeclared identifier
PvSimpleUISampleDlg.cpp(740): error C2065: 'obj' : undeclared identifier
PvSimpleUISampleDlg.cpp(741): error C2065: 'obj' : undeclared identifier
PvSimpleUISampleDlg.cpp(741): error C2653: 'PvSimpleUISample' : is not a class or namespace name
PvSimpleUISampleDlg.cpp(741): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'display'
```

I don't know how it can be done?

Can anybody please help to to solve this problem.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Is this really MFC? gcnew is managed code and it is not MFC.

Comment: @Max This is my code (VC++) and this code is put inside MFC application. Also if gcnew is not used then what will be used to make object of the form and show the form using this object.

Comment: Visual Studio supports two different forms of C++, one is the standard and the other is managed .NET (which in my opinion shouldn't be called C++ at all). You are using conventions from the managed version which are incompatible with the standard, which is what MFC is based on.

Answer (score 0):

What you normally do is create a CDialog (or CDialogEx) based control with an associated dialog form resource and then open it:

```
CMyDialog dlg;
if ( dlg.DoModal() == IDOK )
{
    // User pressed ok
}
```